# Admin to creates users, don't want users to be automatically logged in after admin registering them using Laravel's default Authentication system

Tags: laravel-5

New to frameworks, really have no idea how accomplish this. Somebody help me how to go about this.  The only idea is if i comment out this **$this->guard()->login($user);**, the user will not be logged in automatically. But others like ** How to access the registration page even when the user is logged in**, i really have no idea.

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to create new user from admin panel? Like you have provided separate option to create users?

Comment: Really, i want to create users from admin panel.

Comment: So are you using same route for this? As this is for the peoples to register from frontend. You can create different route for creating users from admin.

Comment: Right now i only have the Admin page but can only view users who are logged in, i haven't worked on users' registration on the Admin's page. So this is why i want help on how to accomplish it.

Comment: so you want to access register blade file hmmm...why don't you simply call showRegistrationForm() method...It has Route type "GET", i think this will work

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thanks @ ViperTecPro.